# c# lambda expression complexity

Tags: c#, lambda, time-complexity

A simple question regarding lambda expression

I wanted to get an average of all trades in following code. The formula I am using is ((price 1*qty 1+(price 2*qty 2)....+(price n*qty n)/(qty 1+qty 2+...+qty n)

In following code, I am using sum function to calculate total of (price*qty) and the complexity will be O(n) and once more time to add up all qty the complexity will be O(n). So, is there any way I can find a summation of both using complexity O(n) means a single lambda expression which can calculate both results.

Using for loop, I can calculate both results in O(n) complexity.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Trade> trades = new List<Trade>()
        {
            new Trade() {price=2,qty=2},
            new Trade() {price=3,qty=3}
        };

         ///using lambda
        int price = trades.Sum(x => x.price * x.qty);
        int qty = trades.Sum(x => x.qty);

        ///using for loop
        int totalPriceQty=0, totalQty=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < trades.Count; ++i)
        {
            totalPriceQty += trades[i].price * trades[i].qty;
            totalQty += trades[i].qty;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Average {0}", qty != 0 ? price / qty : 0);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Trade
{
    public int price;
    public int qty;
}
```

**Edit:** I know that the coefficient does not count. Let me rephrase the question by saying that with lambda we are going to go through each element in the list twice while with for loop we are going to go through each element only once. Is there any solution with lambda so it does not have to go through list elements twice?

Comment: If you have two procedures that are O(n), running one after the other is still O(n).

Comment: I know that but I just wanted to draw attention about double looping through list element when we use lambda

Comment: You might also be interested in reading this article [Parallel Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx).  Just because you're adding a whole bunch of numbers up, doesn't mean you have to do it sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned the Big-O is unchanged, whether you iterate once or twice. If you wanted to use Linq to iterate just **once** you *could* use a custom aggregator (since you are reducing to the same properties we can just use an instance of `Trade` for aggregation):

```
var ag = trades.Aggregate(new Trade(), 
                          (agg, trade) => 
                          { 
                            agg.price += trade.price * trade.qty; 
                            agg.qty += trade.qty; 
                            return agg; 
                          });
int price = ag.price;
int qty = ag.qty;
```

At this point personally I would just use a foreach loop or the simple lambdas you already have - unless performance is crucial here (measure it!)

Answer (score 3):

Big-O complexity does not take consideration of constant coefficients. O(n) + O(n) still gives O(n).

If you’re determined you want to it in lambda, here’s an example using the `Aggregate` operator. It looks contrived, and I wouldn’t recommend it over a traditional for loop.

```
var result = trades.Aggregate(
    Tuple.Create(0, 0),
    (acc, trade) => 
        Tuple.Create(acc.Item1 + trade.price * trade.qty, acc.Item2 + trade.qty));

int totalPrice = result.Item1;
int totalQuantity = result.Item2;
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on BrokenGlass's answer, you could also use an anonymous type as your aggregator like so:

```
var result = trades.Aggregate( 
                 new { TotalValue = 0L, TotalQuantity = 0L }, 
                 (acc, trade) => new 
                 { 
                     TotalValue = acc.TotalValue + trade.price, 
                     TotalQuantity = acc.TotalQuantity + trade.qty
                 }
             );
```

There are two small upsides to this approach:

1. If you're doing this kind of calculation on a large number of trades (or on large trades), it's possible that you would overflow the `int` that keep track of total value of trades and total shares.  This approach lets you specify `long` as your data type (so it would take longer to overflow).
2. The object you get back from this aggregation will have more meaningful properties than you would if you simply returned a `Trade` object.

The big downside is that it's kinda weird to look at.

Comment: I would modify and return the existing accumulator though instead of creating a *new* one for each trade - all of these would have to be garbaged collected(!) - since that is not possible with anonymous types you are out of luck there, the only alternative being creating an entirely new type to hold your accumulated values

Comment: @BrokenGlass: From the perspective of practical efficiency, yes, you’re right. However, creating a new value each time is closer to the functional roots from which LINQ was derived. Altering the object that was passed in to the accumulator function is a bit of a hack. The cleanest approach would probably be to declare a struct.